# Photoshop layer is not displaying

Tags: photoshop

I am a beginner trying to do some designs for my startup.

I am trying to do changes on the Photoshop template:

[image: Photoshop Screenshot]

I simply want to edit the Layer named "Back" and I want to see the content on the display but I can't see the content on the right.

Comment: This would probably be a suitable question for the _Super User_ site. I will see if I can vote to close it here, I think it will automatically migrate there, assuming it gets two other votes to close. Stack Overflow is specifically intended for programming questions.

Comment: rather for Graphic Design SE: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

"Back" is not a layer. It's a "group" and looks like the folder icon. Click those triangles on your other groups `About us` , `Services`, `Slogan`, and you'll see the corresponding layers or additional groups (open up these groups to see layers).